# Is there a maximum amount of money a transaction can handle?

Tags: standard, money-transfer

Apart from the limited transaction size in MB, which theoretically limits the maximum amount of money a transaction can handle, is there any standardized bound?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no limit on the per-input, per-output, fee, or total amount transacted, apart from the fact that all numbers need to be valid BTC amounts (which means not less than 0 and not more than 21M BTC).

Comment: Do you have any source which supports it?

Comment: @CarlosPinzón Well, very large transactions have happened in the past: http://www.coindesk.com/194993-btc-transaction-147m-mystery-and-speculation/ As for a source, this is the code in Bitcoin that checks if a value is between 0 and 21 million coins: https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/3081fb9a31054224759453c3ca400b9076ab8004/src/main.cpp#L944

Answer (score 0):

Transaction outputs are the only place we specify amounts, stored as 64-bit unsigned integers. So we can specify maximum of 92233720368.5 bitcoins in an transaction output.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/ddfd79659e31a41de4e9b824767b766116798a90/src/amount.h#L14

However, there are per-output checks using `bool MoneyRange()`, when a new block is announced. This is more important, since it lowers the maximum amount that can be transacted to the 21-million figure.

https://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin/blob/ddfd79659e31a41de4e9b824767b766116798a90/src/amount.h#L31